# How do I remove jquery

Tags: meteor

I don't need jquery in my meteor app. When I type meteor remove jquery, answer is jquery: not in project.
But jquery is still attached in html.

Comment: What does `meteor list --using` give you?

Comment: As with @Prashant's, If you ran `$().jquery` in your web console do you get anything? If its not in that `list --using` Jquery wouldn't be put in

Comment: Just checked by creating a new project and it looks like `jquery` is being added even when not in `list --using`

Comment: I had a feeling this was the case from a couple of questions before, maybe some core package uses jquery else its a bug

Comment: I thought bootstrap does but then I removed all packages and `$` still returns jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor internals (domutils) depends on JQuery, but I believe the plan is to remove that dependency at some stage:

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/meteor-talk/21y9NbM9v90

Domutils seems to be able to cope without jQuery if sizzle is present (see findAllBySelector).
Doing a quick scan of the code I didn't see any other uses (other than on the server side - in the less parser).

Comment: Ugh.  death to jQuery

Answer (score 1):

To remove/replace jQuery with another version (2.x or 3.x). 
Clone [jquery package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/jquery) from official sources into your project folder `/packages`.

Replace contents of `jquery.js` with anything.

Downloaded package will have a higher priority and will be used instead of original one. Do on your own risk.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I remove jQuery from Meteor.

**Make sure your code really doesn't depend on jQuery before doing this. Also adding any Meteor packages depending on jQuery won't work as expected anymore (e.g: materialize:materialize).**

So, if you want to make sure jQuery is removed from Meteor no matter what, just put

```
Package.describe({
  summary: "Remove jQuery from meteor",
  name: "jquery",
  version: '1.999.999',
});
```

into `packages/jquery/package.js`. No need to clone. No need to add any other files.
Check your `.meteor/versions` file for the entry:

```
jquery@1.999.999
```

to confirm it worked.