# Replace jquery with zepto in meteor

Tags: meteor

I can't seem to figure out how to remove jquery. I found this question [How do I remove jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15385115/how-do-i-remove-jquery) from earlier this year, but I can't find any up to date information. Is it possible to remove jquery from meteor? meteor remove jquery says that jquery is not included in the project, but it is included in the generated html. I'd like to replace it with something a bit more lightweight like zepto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this moment this is probably not possible to do, as Meteor internals depend on JQuery. You can try to remove it and replace by Zepto, but most probably it won't work (this may change in a later release of Meteor).

`jquery` package is not included itself in a blank Meteor app. Instead, it's loaded by [`standard-app-packages`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/standard-app-packages/package.js). So to remove it, you need to remove `standard-app-packages` and then add all packages [listed here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/standard-app-packages/package.js#L16-L43), except of course JQuery.

Comment: Soon, the new rendering model will not be based explicitly on jQuery. You will be able to choose any framework you want to perform inserts, removes or animations of UI. It will be available with Meteor 1.0.